# How to create a gml file from Java code

Tags: java, gml-geographic-markup-lan

I want to create an application which require to create a .gml file using Java. And I want to add elements in that newly created .gml file from a text file.

How can I do so?

Comment: Can you narrow down your question? Currently a valid answer would be *by typing Java code in a text editor*.

Comment: Alright, looks like [GML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_Markup_Language) is an XML based markup. I have no clue what you mean by converting text file to GML file! Perhaps rename the extension?

Comment: You must show us what the text file looks like (just a small section) - we cannot help you otherwise

Comment: GML stands for Game Maker Language. What the hell are you guys even talking about? Wrong tag. haha

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that you have legacy output of some form without explicit markup and that it has geo-coordinates in it. There is no simple or easy answer to that - we are engaged in writing parsers that will extract geo-coordinates from free text and it's a long process, involving heuristics and without 100% recall/precision.

Sometimes you have semi-structured documents - such as Wikipedia and it is easier - but not trivial - to write a geo-coordinate scraper.

But you should give more details of your potential inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Since GML is an XML dialect, I'd say the best way is to  take your [GML application schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GML_Application_Schemas) and use JAX-B to generate an Object model from it, then parse the text format, transfer the data to the objext model and use JAX-B to marshal it to XML.

Answer (score -2):

All a .gml file is a file that starts with **#define script_name**
Then you put your code below that.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'put you code below'? How does the OP create new elements?

Comment: A .gml file looks like this:                                 #define my_script                                                          //ALL GML CODE HERE